# 2 arrays insert via (column) double dimension array ruby (short method)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

From this initialize array:

```
x = []
y = [1,2,3,4,5]
z = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

I want `x` result to be like this:

```
=> [[1,"a"], [2,"b"], [3,"c"], [4,"d"], [5,"e"]]
```

Is there any short method to do this without using nested loop?

Comment: `y.zip(z)` #=> [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"], [4, "d"], [5, "e"]]

Comment: [y, z].transpose # => => [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"], [4, "d"], [5, "e"]] or 
z.map.with_index { |_, idx| [y[idx], z[idx]] } # => same response